# does eBPF support events?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

Is is possible to have `ebpf` program generate event, for example packet counter reached a predefined threshold value and `ebpf` would generate some notification/event to user, something similar to what `netlink` provides.

I see that currently the only way to signal this event/state is via `maps` which can be polled by the user application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way currently to signal userspace or other programs without polling maps.

This has been [briefly discussed](https://lists.iovisor.org/pipermail/iovisor-dev/2018-February/001226.html) on the iovisor-dev mailing list before. If you have a use case for this, you might try to bring it on the mailing list.

Comment: thank you for the link! It suggests interesting idea to use `ftrace` to trace the map update calls, I should try it.

Comment: Glad I could help! Note that you can also use BPF directly instead of ftrace to trace calls to `bpf_map_update_elem`. Anything you want me to add in the answer to accept it?

Comment: I have another question. Is the tracing the calls (with `ftrace`, `tracepoints`) considered async mechanism?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "async."...?

Comment: For example, I can subscribe ip events (add/delete FIB rules), or network interfaces events (link up/down) via `setsockopt`, events will show up on the netlink socket, where I run `select()`, so there is no need to continuously poll the socket. How does ftrace work compared to my example?

Comment: As far as I know you'll have to poll with ftrace too.